# Java Braintree check transaction

Tags: java, braintree

I have a confusion with Braintree. When a customer orders certain item on site, he makes a charge on BT with his credit card and I need to check this payment via Java client. I found the following code:

```
Transaction transaction = gateway.transaction().find("the_transaction_id");
```

But I need to search by orderId, a special ID that my system issues on every order event. How to do that in BT with Java API?

Answer (score 2):

Although you may be able to persist the orderId on the Braintree side, I don't readily see a way to perform a lookup on it directly.

Here's how we handle it:

Persist your orderId with the transaction ID that you get back from Braintree.  When you need to do your check, look up your table using the orderId, find the transactionId, and call the same `find()` method to find the payment.

I'd imagine you'd do something like:

```
//some paymentService
public Result<Transaction> sale(BigDecimal amount,
                                String nonce,
                                String firstName,
                                String lastName,
                                String postalCode) {

    TransactionRequest request = new TransactionRequest()
            .customer()
            .firstName(firstName)
            .lastName(lastName) 
            .done()
            .billingAddress()
            .firstName(firstName)
            .lastName(lastName)
            .postalCode(postalCode)
            .done()
            .type(Type.SALE)
            .amount(amount)
            .paymentMethodNonce(nonce)
            .options()
            .submitForSettlement(true)
            .done();

    return gateway.transaction().sale(request);
}

//and then...

Result<Transaction> result = paymentService.sale(amount, nonce, firstName, lastName, postalCode);
   if (result.isSuccess()) {
       Transaction transaction = result.getTarget();
       String transactionId = transaction.getId(); //persist this ID and your orderId together in your DB
   ...
}

//when you need to find payment details, it'd be like:
Order order = someService.find(orderId); 
PaymentHistory paymentHistory = order.getPaymentHistory();
String transactionId = paymentHistory.getTransactionId();
Transaction transaction = gateway.transaction().find(transactionId);
```